# Synchronize Issues in Mantis and in JIRA

Tags: jira, mantis

We are moving from Mantis to JIRA and wish to keep Mantis alive for some time until the migration is complete and all the users are migrated.

All users (esp. the dev team) that have been migrated to JIRA shouldn't continue with Mantis (maybe deactivate accounts) and concentrate on JIRA alone.

Thus if a Mantis issue that was migrated to JIRA gets fixed/commented (in JIRA) the new status should be synchronized to the still existing Mantis issue.

And (if possible) new issues that are created in Mantis should be automatically be added to JIRA (if this is not possible then thats OK too)

Does anybody know of a tool or plugin that can do this?

Comment: Would you care to share why you moved away from Mantis? As a developer of Mantis, I'm curious about your reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know any tool that does it, but in our company we have successfully implemented sync tool for Jira<->Footprints and Jira<->CRM. It would use Jira SOAP API (or REST starting from 5.0) and Mantis SOAP API. This tool can regularly check issues in both systems and update them accordingly.

Jira SOAP API - http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/index.html?com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html

Jira REST API - https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your own sync using Jira's REST API as @Daria replied above, or you can use Task Adapter for manual [data synchronization between Jira and Mantis](http://www.taskadapter.com/atlassian-jira).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no immediate answer, but we are developing an internal tool for exactly this purpose:

- migrate existing issues from Mantis -> JIRA
- ability to enter new issues in Mantis and have them synced to JIRA
- activity in JIRA issues replicated back to Mantis
- workflow disabled in Mantis (issues are slaved to JIRA state)
- keep Mantis alive for N months while users are trained and migrated

It is using their SOAP and REST APis respectively.

If there is interest and it works well (looking really good at this stage) I will seek permission to open source it.

Comment: Did you open source it? I'm looking for a solution for this problem as well.

Comment: Likewise, did you open source it?